# C# lock does not work on invoked method

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

I've just started programming in C#, and I've stumbled upon a small problem - **lock** doesn't seem to work and I get a "**Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.**" exception.

My code basically works like this:

```
private static object myLock = new object();

private Stack<MyObject> myObjects;

....

// Method that throws an exception
public void Update()
{
    lock(myLock)
    {
        foreach (MyObject ob in myObjects)
        {
            ob.Update(); // has a foreach loop of it's own
        }
    }

}

// Method invoked by a click event
public void InvokedMethod()
{
    lock(myLock)
    {
        myObjects.Push(new MyObject());
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you !

Comment: What are you doing within the `foreach`? And why is that section important enough to be shown if you are simply iterating over `screens` and not `myObjects` in it?

Comment: Please show more code. Are you perhaps calling `InvokedMethod` from within the loop?

Comment: Try it with empty foreach or only print something into console in foreach

Comment: Ok, that edit helped. Now show us the definition of `MyObject.Update`.

Comment: Nevermind, guys - I've fixed it. Thanks for your help and sorry about an awful code sample:). Since I figured out that it had a problem within the foreach loop, it was an easy fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely to do with the code that you haven't included inside the foreach block - what are you doing in the code you've missed out?  If you're modifying the screens collection (add or remove), this will cause the exception you have seen.